# How can I make the supertabular caption look the the normal one?

Tags: captions, ieeetran, supertabular

Using `supertabular` in a document class which defines their own caption format is not ideal:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{This is what I want.}
    \end{table}

    \tablecaption{This is what I get.}
    \begin{supertabular}{l}
    \end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way for `supertabular` to use the same caption format as the rest of the document? I am showing an `IEEEtran` example here, but I am actually interested in using this in `ieeecolor` - so a general solution would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{supertabular,capt-of}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \caption{This is what I want.}
    \end{table}


\begin{supertabular}{l}
\noalign{\captionof{table}{This is what I get.}}
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to put this inside `\tablefirsthead` since I generate the table with `pgfplotstabletypeset` and did not see another way to write after the column specifiers, and that is generally working fine. Just need `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` to fix numbering of tables - it seems the contents of `\tablefirsthead` is evaluated twice. (I hope that is constant and not due to the fact the the table spans 2 columns...)